# PHP HTML if then else statement

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to use php (if then else) statement to open another link if first condition is not met. But this code does not work and it's only pointing to the first condition. Please find my codes below

Screen shot of the table

[image: [1]]

NOTE: Used code from an answer below, but it only shows the first table button

```
<?php

$result = odbc_exec($conn,"SELECT tblParity.pxservice as service, tblPatients.Lname as Lname, tblPatients.mi as mi, tblPatients.Fname as fname, tblPatients.PhoneNum as PhoneNum, DATE_FORMAT(Bday,'%m / %d / %Y')as Bday, YEAR(now()) - YEAR(tblPatients.Bday) - ( DAYOFYEAR(now()) < DAYOFYEAR(tblPatients.Bday) ) as pxAge, tblPatients.PatientID as PatientID, DATE_FORMAT(tblOBGyne.obgyneDate,'%m-%d-%Y') as obgyneDate, TIME_FORMAT(tblOBGyne.obgyneTime, '%h:%i%p') as obgyneTime, tblParity.ParityID, tblOBGyne.OBGyneID

FROM tblPatients
JOIN tblParity ON tblPatients.PatientID = tblParity.PatientID
JOIN tblOBGyne ON tblParity.ParityID = tblOBGyne.ParityID
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(tblobgyne.obgyneDate, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() ORDER BY tblobgyne.obgyneTime ASC; ");

while($row = odbc_fetch_row($result))
{


?>
<tr>

<td class="center">

<?php
$service= odbc_result($result,"service");
$link = "";
$uServ = strtoupper($service);

if ($uServ=="GYNECOLOGY") $link = "recordgyne.php";
elseif ($uServ=="OBSTERICS") $link = "recordob.html";
?>
<?php if ($link !== "") { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $link."?pxid=".odbc_result($result,"PatientID"); ?>
&parid=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"ParityID"); ?>
&obgyneid=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID"); ?>"><span class="label label-default"><i class="icon-file-text"></i></span></a>
<?php } ?>

&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="pxconsold.php?id=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID"); ?>"><span class="label label-warning"><i class="icon-edit"></i></span></a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="php/delete.php?id=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID"); ?>"><span class="label label-danger"><i class="icon-trash"></i></span></a>
</td>
<td hidden="text"><?php echo odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo odbc_result($result,"Lname"); ?>
, &nbsp;<?php echo odbc_result($result,"Fname"); ?>
&nbsp;<?php echo odbc_result($result,"mi"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo odbc_result($result,"Bday");?></td>
<td><?php echo odbc_result($result,"pxAge"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo odbc_result($result,"PhoneNum"); ?></td>
<td ><?php echo odbc_result($result,"service"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo odbc_result($result,"obgyneTime"); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
odbc_close($conn);// Closes ODBC Connection to DB
?>
```

Comment: Please provide MINIMAL code necessary to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your if syntax is incorrect.

```
if($service == 'Gynecology' or $service == 'GYNECOLOGY'): ?>
<a href="recordgyne.php?pxid=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"PatientID"); ?>
&parid=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"ParityID"); ?>
&obgyneid=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID"); ?>"><span class="label label-default"><i class="icon-file-text"></i></span></a>

<?php elseif($service == 'Obstetrics' or $service == 'OBSTERICS'): ?>
<a href="recordob.html?pxid=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"PatientID"); ?>
&parid=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"ParityID"); ?>
&obgyneid=<?php echo odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID"); ?>"><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-file-text"></i></span></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This looks like a ternary tried to get in there. What is the `:` doing? 'GYNECOLOGY'): <<<

Comment: It's other format of `if/else` syntax that usually using in templates. See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: there are services that are not capitalize ao i was wondring maybe it will not much the condition. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please accept the answer. @MjEliad

Answer (score 0):

1. `=` is assignment `==` is test for equality
2. DRY (Don't repeat yourself)
3. Spell OBSTETRICS correctly ;)

Assuming NO link if neither Gynecology nor Obstetrics try this:

```
$link = "";
$uServ = strtoupper($service);

if ($uServ=="GYNECOLOGY") $link = "recordgyne.php";
elseif ($uServ=="OBSTETRICS") $link = "recordob.html";

<?php if ($link !== "") { 
  $link.="?pxid=".odbc_result($result,"PatientID")."&parid=".odbc_result($result,"ParityID")."&obgyneid=".odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID");
?>
  <a href="<?= $link ?>"><span class="label label-default"><i class="icon-file-text"></i></span></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I may have made some syntax error. I made a new version - can you check PHP errors? I am a JavaScript person - only do PHP when I have to :)

Comment: There is no error at all, its just that the button is not showing.

Comment: So maybe $service is neither GYNECOLOGY nor OBSTERICS - try echoing it

Comment: The button cameup but it only shows the first table.

Comment: You have not posted enough code for me to understand what that means "only shows the first table"

Comment: Wiat ill post the whole table code to give the picture.

Comment: Can you try my updated code and I have added that you are using code from an answer to not confuse people coming after. Your issue has changed now I believe. I will be away from keyboard for several hours now

Comment: Tried again but still showing the same.. By the way it only shows the first row table button. i have attached the screenshot on my post.

Comment: I noticed the that "OBSTERICS" in the code is wrong spell so i corrected it to "OBSTETRICS", then the code works like a magic.. ty alot!